# PHP string can only contain 0 1 and spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently working on a PHP script, and i need to check a string.
If the string contains other characters than 0 1 and spaces, then i would like to return an error. If the string only contains 0 1 and spaces then continue with the code.

The string is user submitted, and therefore it can be very long.

I have tried searching the web for a solution, but i cant find exactly what i am looking for.

But i have a feeling that i am going to use regex to solve my problem. I have found the following code:

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-1]$/', $txt_string) == 1) {

    return "Ok";

} else {

    return "Error";

}
```

But the problem here is that it seems to fail when i insert more than one number.

/Morten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the quantifier, and `[0-1]` is effectively equivalent to `[01]`. Also, it seems like you forgot to include spaces in your character class. You can add it, if you want them to match.

So, your regex should be:

```
'/^[01 ]+$/'
```

Comment: Ahh. We are approaching what I was looking for. But I can see that it does not accept line breaks. Can we make it accept them too?

Comment: @MortenHolmChristensen. You need to enable `MULTILINE` mode. Which I don't know how you do in `php regex`. You can search for it.

Comment: @RohitJain you don't. All it does is to make `^$` match newlines.

Comment: @JanDvorak. Ah! Seems like, I misinterpreted what OP meant. Yeah then in that case, we can make the whole pattern optional like this: - `'/^([01 ]+)?$/'`

Comment: @JanDvorak.. Ah! Crap. Line break. Line break. Why I forgot it's meaning. Thanks though for correcting me.

Comment: And yet it don't work.. As i am testing it seems to accept the number 7 too??

Comment: Now that is not possible. What tool are you using to test?

Comment: @MortenHolmChristensen. I bet you didn't use anchors. `^` and `$`. Did you?

Comment: It looks like this: '/[01 \n]+$/'

Comment: @MortenHolmChristensen.. Nono. You also need to add `^` at the beginning. Use : `'/^[01 \n]+$/'`